# Converting `NSDecimalNumber` to `SInt64` without precision loss. (within range of SInt64, iOS)

Tags: ios, precision, numeric

Currently, `[NSDecimalNumber longLongValue]` created with string `@"9999999999999999"` returns `10000000000000000`.

This means the class converts it's value to `double` first, and re-converts into `SInt64`(`signed long long`)

How to evade this behavior? I want to get precise integral number within the range of `SInt64`.

PS.
I considered about converting to `NSString` and re-converting into `SInt64` with `NSScanner` or `strtoll`, but I believe there's better way. But if you sure about there's no other way, please tell me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: unless you're sure it's performance-critical, I'd write it into a string and scan it back. That's the easy way.

Now, if you really want to do it otherwise:

1. get an `NSDecimal` from your `NSDecimalNumber`
2. work with the private fields of the structure, initialize your `long long` value from the mantissa (possibly introduce checks to handle too-large mantissas)
3. multiply by 10^exponent; you can do that using [binary exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring); again, check for overflow

Comment: Thanks for answer! #2 seems more faster than #1. However, #1 is better way as you mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

Start with an NSDecimalNumber* originalValue.

Let int64_t approx = [originalValue longLongValue]. This will not be exact, but quite close.

Convert approx to NSDecimalNumber, calculate originalValue - approx, take the longLongValue, and add to approx. Now you got the correct result.